# Lighttpd Rewrite

Tags: lighttpd, rewrite

I have an issue with Lighttpd Rewrite and static files.

Here is my rewrite syntax:

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(.*)\.(php|css|js|jpg|png)$" => "$0",
    "^/(.+)$" => "/router.php?url=$1"
)
```

All .css and .js files load up just fine but no images load up. I have attempted check if the file is being served from /images but that does not fix the issue. I checked the access logs and all css and js files have a 200 status but all image files have a 404. The paths are correct.

Does anyone have an idea why the .css and .js files would load properly but images do not.

Comment: Instead of url.rewrite, try url.rewrite_once; and also check the extensions of your images

Answer (score 1):

If you change `url.rewrite =` to `url.rewrite-if-not-file =` this may fix the issues you are having.